# How to convert a nested dict to dict-of-lists?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, type-conversion

I have an input file that consist of multiple nested dicts as shown below:

```
input= {"md5": "36a4d23084085455409e4fc2c8655e47",
        "sha1": "13f24657a8823b5e076b841ab5dfa1db5aa3825d",
        "sha256": "fffaeb0de998f17d1e58bd1329241dc4181f6c8e367c6dae7d289dd52294538d",
        "av_labels": {"Avast": {"result": None},
                      "Avira": {"result": None},
                         .................
                      "Eset": {"result": "Trojan/Win32.Tepfer"}
                     }
       }
```

And I have to convert that to something like below to work in another program.

```
output= {"md5": "36a4d23084085455409e4fc2c8655e47",
         "sha1": "13f24657a8823b5e076b841ab5dfa1db5aa3825d",
         "sha256": "fffaeb0de998f17d1e58bd1329241dc4181f6c8e367c6dae7d289dd52294538d",
         "av_labels": [ ["Avast", None],
                        ["Avira", None],
                           ............
                        ["Eset", "Trojan/Win32.Tepfer"]
                      ]
        }
```

I think actually should convert value of `"av_labels"` key from dict-of_dict to list-of-lists and remove `"result"` keys.

I saw some technique of converting dict to list but I don't get my expected result. I use python 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do so by reassigning 'av_labels' key using list comprehension. I've changed your variable name to `a`, as input is a [built-in function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html) of python.

```
a['av_labels'] = [[k, v['result']] for k, v in a['av_labels'].items()]


{'av_labels': [['Avast', None],
               ['Avira', None],
               ['Eset', 'Trojan/Win32.Tepfer']],
 'md5': '36a4d23084085455409e4fc2c8655e47',
 'sha1': '13f24657a8823b5e076b841ab5dfa1db5aa3825d',
 'sha256': 'fffaeb0de998f17d1e58bd1329241dc4181f6c8e367c6dae7d289dd52294538d'}
```

Comment: Yes, I forgot. I just named it for example, it was my mistake. Thanks for your answer. that's what i expected.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can convert it to tuples. A tuple is basicly an immutable list.

```
d["av_labels"] = list(zip(d["av_labels"].keys(),map(lambda x: list(x.values())[0],d["av_labels"].values())))
```

Comment: Ty but it raise AttributeError... It said list don't have attribute keys.